# In using NSFetchedResultsController, Is it possible to combine attributes from coredata in the header

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift3

I am using NSFetchedResultsController with a UITableViewController. The sections are delineated based on

`fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: noteRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Note.id), cacheName: nil)`

Is there a way I can combine the attribute Note.id with another attribute (Note.date) without creating a new attribute?

Comment: How we answer depends on what you'd like to achieve... for example, what data types are you attempting to combine and for what reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The `sectionNameKeyPath` can be any property - not necessarily one defined by core-date - that the object can handle. You can add a property to your managedObject subclass based on anything you want and use it for a sectionName.  **BUT** the the sectionsNames must conform to the same order as your data, and the sort descriptors must be based on core-data properties.  For example, if you data was ordered by Date you could have sections based on the day, or the hour but not based on Importance - you wanted sections based on Importance you would first need to sort based on it.

Keep in mind is that sectionNames have to be unique, but do not need to be what you display.  So if you were sorting by date, and sectioning by hour you shouldn't use sectionNames of 1:00, 2:00 etc because they would not be unique (they repeat every day).  Instead you should use 2017-03-01-1:00 or the like.  But then why you display the header you can display only the 1:00.

Also the method that is used for the sectionName is called for *every single element* when the fetchedResultsController loads.  So don't do anything resource intensive there - like make a date formatter.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. A very lucid answer.